# How do I make sure that I don't loop through the same element in a list if i previously added it to another list?

Tags: python

The problem is that I am trying to create a wordle game, and whenever I loop through the list of user_inputed characters and see if an individual character is in a list of characters from a randomized word, it identifies the same character as the loop before and prints another statement which I dont want it to do. Here is the code:

```
def guess_words(word_list, gameBoard):
    i = 0

    while i < 6:
        guessed = input("Enter 5 letter Word: ").upper()
        if not guessed.isalpha() or len(guessed) != 5 or guessed.lower() not in get_words():
            print("Invalid Word")
            continue
        else:
            for letter, guess in enumerate(guessed):
                if guess == word_list[letter]:
                    gameBoard[letter] = guess
                elif guess in word_list and guess != word_list[letter] and word_list[letter] not in gameBoard:
                    print(f"The letter {guess} is somewhere else.")

        i += 1
        print(gameBoard)

        if i >= 6 and "-" in gameBoard:
            sys.exit("You Lost")

        if "-" not in gameBoard:
            sys.exit("You Win!")

        print(f"Guesses Left: {6 - i}")
```

I tried many things to fix this, but cannot figure out the correct solution.

For example: if the randomly selected word is could, and I inputted rotor as my first guess, the program should show that the first o was placed correctly, and no other messages are placed on the screen. However, I am getting the message, The letter O is somewhere else, because the second O is not in word (and therefor thinks it is in the wrong place).

Comment: But the second "o" would be in the wrong place in the example given...  perhaps you want to explain further ?  or provide an example : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Alright thanks for the assistance i beleive I figured it out by creating another list and then looping through that

Comment: Never mind I never solved it. The phrase "The Letter O is somewhere else" should not be triggered by a letter that is already in the gameBoard, and also if there is only one O in the word_list, then when user inputting rotor should not give two somewhere else print statements.